# Is it possible to call a script from within another script in Octave?

Tags: matlab, file, octave, external

PHP has the nifty `include()` function to bring in external files into the main script. Is this possible in Octave? I tried using `load()` but I keep getting an error: `error: load: unable to determine the file format of 't_whse.m'` which makes me think this is the wrong way to do this or that it's actually not possible in Octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `load`, as `load` is reserved for loading data from a file. Instead, you just want to call the script by name. This will (if it's actually a script) execute the script and make any variables that were defined in that script accessible to the calling script.

**`script1.m`**

```
disp('Beginning of script1');
script2;
fprintf('Value = %d\n', value)
disp('End of script1')
```

**`script2.m`**

```
disp('Beginning of script2');
value = 2;
disp('End of script 2');
```